# AWS Lambda event filtering using "exists"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb-streams

According to the [AWS Lambda event filtering](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-eventfiltering.html), you can filter events by the existence of keys like so `{"foo":[{"exists":true}]}`. However, through much trial and error, I found that this **only applies to keys that contain a JSON *primitive* and not a nested structure**.

e.g. the above filter will work for

```json
{
   "foo": "bar"
}
```

but not for

```json
{
  "foo": { "baz": "bar"}
}
```

If you wanted to match the latter event, your filter will need to drill e.g. `{"foo":{"baz":[{"exists":true}]}}`

This can be especially easy to miss when triggering on Dynamo steams events since the payload is in DynamoJSON format.

Is this a bug or intentional?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question other than to say it's probably intentional, because the filtering is based on EventBridge's and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-event-patterns.html states that 'field names must also appear in the event with the same nesting structure'. But - thank you for creating this question and saving my sanity. I have proposed an update to the specific DynamoDB docs page that gets this wrong: https://github.com/awsdocs/amazon-dynamodb-developer-guide/pull/312